# glbindframebuffer Error in MonoGame Windows OpenGL Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opengl, monogame

I have been having issues with MonoGame and getting it to work at first it was the SDL.dll then it was the OpenAL that I had to download then now. Whenever I try to run the project it gives me a `Unable to find an entry point named 'glBindFramebuffer' in DLL 'opengl32.dll'.` error.

I also get errors when creating a Android or Content templates but im just trying to get this to work I've done some research and the only solution is wraping it around a try/catch block but I feel as if that is something that can give me issues later on I would gladly appreciate the help.

Im using VS 2010 but gives me the error in both VS 2010 and 2012.

Screenshot :

[image]

Code :

```
public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public Game1() : base()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this); // Throws EntryPointNotFoundException
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what this error is really saying is that it can't find the *correct* version of the DLL's because it can't find a method in the DLL that should be there.

The DLL's you are having problems with are unmanaged code and therefore are not copied to your output directory automatically because they can't be added to the project as references.

It's entirely possible that your game is trying to use DLLs somewhere else on your system (like the Windows\System32 folder). Try finding the correct DLL's from the MonoGame install directory and copying them to your bin\Debug\ folder.

If that works you can add the file to your solution as a link and set it to copy to the output folder on build. This way, you won't have to do it manually if you 'clean' the project.